# Form refreshing even when Javascript validation is returning False

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

My form is refreshing even when my validation in JavaScript returns false.

The form submit button:

```
<button type="submit"   value="Submit" id="sign-in" tabindex="3" name="submit" type="submit" 
onclick="submit_data()">
```

the JavaScript function:

```
function submit_data(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;

    if(validateEmail(document.getElementById('name').value)){
    {
        return false;
    } else
        if(msg == ""){
            return false;
        } else{
            send_data(name, msg);    

            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = "index2.php?n="+name;
            }, 2000);        
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your `{` and `}`

Comment: You would need to be using `onsubmit` of a `<form>` for `return false;` to stop the submission.

Comment: _“even when my validation in JavaScript returns false”_ – that’s because you are not passing that return value along, but let it disappear into thin air instead. When you do “old-school” event handling via HTML attributes, then you need to pass the return value of the function “up one level” in your event handler attribute, so that it actually prevents the event default action. `<button type="submit" […] onclick="return submit_data()">`